# Python - loop column names

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I can't find solution to my problem. I have dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'B':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})
```

I'd like to make 5 new columns B_1, B_2, ..., B_5 in which i would like define cells based on function x-i, where x is cell value and i is iteration step (1,..,5) - it would be enough to have desired result for column B.
B_1 should be [6,7,8,3,1,2] etc..
Can you please give me some hints?

Thanks

Comment: So `df['B_1'] = df['B'] - 1`?

Comment: yeah, but would be glad to see solution using loop. I need it for larger and more complicated data sets.

Comment: it would be helpful if u provide ur expected output, just as u posted an input dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of having five iterations, and them being known in advance:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    for i in range(1, 6):
        df[f'{col}_{i}'] = df[col] - i
```

Comment: thanks, works really good, but something is wrong when my column name have more than one letter in name; do you know what's happening? for example for name 'Age' instead of 'A'

Comment: Shouldn't matter. `df.columns` is a list of strings, whether it contains `'A'` or `'Age'` is indifferent to the rest of the code.

Comment: I changed column name 'A' for 'Age' and tried to do the same thing just for this column, but this time some error is happening
`
for col in df.columns[0]:
    for i in range(1, 6):
        df[f'{col}_{i}'] = df[col] - i`

Comment: Why did you add `[0]`?

Comment: The it's going to loop through the string letter by letter. If you only want it for a certain column just `col = 'A' ` and get rid of the first for loop.

Comment: Works fine. Do you know how to add loop results to list? I've got something like this - used function from sklearn, which gives some value for two columns.
`from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
acc = []
col='Age'
for i in range(2, 8):
        df[f'{col}_{i}'] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x-2*i)
acc.append(roc_auc_score(df['D'],df[f'{col}_{i}']))
print(acc)`

I just see last result of this roc_auc_score function. How to add every iteration to list? What's wrong here?

Comment: You don't have to score it every time, you can just run `roc_auc_score` after the loop. But please close this question and open a new one if you have a different issue.